# issue with tfjs converter for a saved_model - weights not saved and weights_manifest.json only has the output node

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'm struggling to figure out how to properly save a tensorflow model that was saved as a saved_model method and convert it to tensorflow.js.  when I currently convert it it ends up with a `weights_manifest.json` containing only one set of weights.

The model I want to convert is from this jupyter notebook .[RNN for Human Activity Recognition - 2D Pose Input](https://github.com/stuarteiffert/RNN-for-Human-Activity-Recognition-using-2D-Pose-Input#rnn-for-human-activity-recognition---2d-pose-input).

The full code for building and training the graph can be found in that jupyter notebook.

I can successfully run the code:

```
save_path = "/content/gdrive/My Drive/saved_model/"

tf.saved_model.simple_save(sess,
  save_path,
  inputs={"x":x},
  outputs={"y": y})
```

From looking at the graph building code I'm not entirely sure what the `output_node_names` should be in the `tensorflowjs_converter` command, because when I put in `y` I get an error that the node does not exist. I printed out all the graph nodes and am guessing it's `mul_1/y`, as this is what's in the graph building code:

```
def LSTM_RNN(_X, _weights, _biases):
    # model architecture based on "guillaume-chevalier" and "aymericdamien" under the MIT license.

    _X = tf.transpose(_X, [1, 0, 2])  # permute n_steps and batch_size
    # rest of graph building code left out for this post
    # Linear activation
    return tf.matmul(lstm_last_output, _weights['out']) + _biases['out']
```

When I run the command:

```
!tensorflowjs_converter \
    --input_format=tf_saved_model \
    --output_node_names="mul_1/y" \
    --saved_model_tags=serve \
    /content/gdrive/My\ Drive/saved_model/ \
    /content/gdrive/My\ Drive/web_model/
```

It succeeds with this message:

> Using TensorFlow backend. 2019-02-23 01:46:53.475557: I
>   tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports
>   instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
>   FMA Writing weight file /content/gdrive/My
>   Drive/web_model/tensorflowjs_model.pb...

However, the tensorflowjs_model.pb file is only 50 bytes, and all that's contained within weights_manifest.json is:

```
[{"paths": ["group1-shard1of1"], "weights": [{"name": "mul_1/y", "shape": [], "dtype": "int32"}]}]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `output_node_names` is the name of the node you want to return. You can give a name to your tensorflow operation and that name will serve as `output_name`.

```
return tf.add(tf.matmul(lstm_last_output, _weights['out']), _biases['out'] , name="y")
```

Then you can use `--output_node_names="y"` in your converter.

Lastly to execute your code in js

```js
const model = await tf.loadFrozenModel(MODEL_URL, WEIGHTS_URL);

// define a tensor t
const y = model.execute({
    "x": t // x input_name of the tensorflow graph
  });
// it will return the output node y value
```